# Power on over SSH

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to power on Ubuntu over SSH or some kind of networking? I'm using Lubuntu on a laptop and want to switch on without opening the lid.

Answer (score 2):

You need wake up by lan support by your laptop.

> Introduction
>
> Wake-on-LAN enables users to turn on a computer across a network from
>   another network device. It can be very useful in situations where
>   computers are not all next to each other or there are a lot of
>   machines. WoL works by sending a packet of data called a Magic Packet™
>   to the target machine. When the packet is received, the target
>   machine's network device (Network Interface Controller or NIC)
>   wakes-up the rest of the machine.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan